# including id in url map with submitToRemote tag

Tags: grails, view, gsp, parameters

I'm building a list of results from a query, and for each result, I want them to be able to select one, and have that result come on the same page.  I could use radio buttons and an additional submit button, but I don't like the way that looks with the results.  My preferred solution would be to have a button or a link to each result and have that update the proper div on select.  I'm trying to use `submitToRemote` for this:

```
<g:each in="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <g:submitToRemote value="${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}" 
                url="[action: 'modifyUser', id:'${user.id}']" update ="adminSpace"
                class="btn btn-primary"/>
        ...
```

The problem is that id field in the url, I'm sure I'm not accessing it correctly, but I cannot for the life of me find the proper syntax.

Currently I'm getting:

```
Message: named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
```

I've looked at the documentation ([submitToRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html)), Where it says:

> url - The url to submit to, either a map containing keys for the action, controller and id or a string value

however it doesn't give any indication on how to specify the id.  When I manually add a value for the id it does work (such as:

```
url="[action: 'modifyUser', id: '1']"
```

).  That however isn't incredibly useful.  So how do I get the id passed through to my action within the confines of the submitToRemote?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.3.8  if that's helpful at all...

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to use the createLink method? Something like:

```
<g:submitToRemote value="${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}" 
                url="${createLink(action: 'modifyUser', id: user.id)}" update ="adminSpace"
                class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Comment: This gave me a method not found error, because the url field is actually calling this method, and it doesn't accept a string.  So your answer got me on the right track:
`url="${[action: 'modifyUser', id: user.id]}"`
Which is what I needed.  If edit your answer with that in it, I'll accept it since it put me on the right course.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put `user.id` in `${}` like:

```
<g:submitToRemote value="${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}" 
    url="[action: 'modifyUser', id: user.id]" update="adminSpace" 
    class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

and your code works fine.